# What can I do if I object the close reason but I have no enough reputation to cast reopen vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

Sometimes I see some questions are closed but I think the closed reason is not reasonable (an example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212712), which I know what OP is asking well, and can even predict the answer without reading current comments and answers, but now closed as unclear)

Unfortunately I have no enough reputation to reopen a question, and the flag option doesn't have reopen option. Is there anything I can do if object the close reason but no enough reputation?

Comment: You may want to find better question than "array length in Java or C"... (Plus I suspect it already was hit by meta-effect once based on number of votes :) )

Comment: Note that this example question you link to was tagged with [tag:c], [tag:java], and [tag:android] (I removed the Java tag just not, as it's *probably* about C since the accepted answer is in C). So yes, I would say that's pretty "unclear" since it's not even clear what the question is about! It's like asking "I need to know the current regulations regarding a mortgage since I'm buying a house. I may live in Belgium or Lithuania".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do nothing is good option - there is a very good chance that the same question is asked many times - in linked case you should be able to find some reasonably easily and act on opened once (i.e. answer there).

If you really want to do something with question:

- one obvious option - edit question in shape (i.e. make it clear, clarify why it is different from existing similar question to avoid duplicate,...), add comment and let question automatically show up in re-open queue.
- if you found clear, unique and useful question in existing "unclear"/"too broad" post - you can ask that question yourself (may be link to original).
- you can ask for help in corresponding chat rooms (you'd need good and convincing explanation why it should be reopened)

About specific question you've linked to - it asks about C and Java solution - which does not make a lot of sense since languages are quite different making post  very unclear. Additionally same question asked multiple times for each language and question will be immediately closed as duplicate of one.

Comment: `same question asked multiple times` For instance, questions about fixing a `java.lang.NullPointerException`?